# Is that possible to generate gtk via command

Tags: dm-script

Hi, all

Previously, I added my script to GMS menu by using GMS GUI. And it will generate a gtk file which can be shared to other users. But now I'd like to use command line to achieve this, so that I can integrate this into my python script.

Is there any good solution? Thanks in advance.

Regards

Chen ZX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to do this from a command-line prompt. This is not possible - at least not without starting GMS in the process. The "compilation" of .s files into .gtk files is done by the GMS application.

However, it is possible to launch GMS from a command-line prompt to have it execute a script at startup using the `/ef` command-line parameter.

It is done like this:

> `"C:\Program Files\Gatan\digitalmicrograph" /offline /ef "c:\Scripts\MyScript.s"`
>
> - `/ef` will attempt to execute the provided file as a script-file
> - `"c:\Scripts\MyScript.s"` is the path to the DM-script files to be executed.
> - `/offline` starts GMS without loading any of the hardware related DLLs. It is optional here.

---

As for installing .s files from within a GMS script:

Please consult the F1 help documentation:

It explains all necessary steps including example code.

[image]

and:
[image]

Comment: Very useful answer. Did not realize options exist for DM command-line launch. Are these documented somewhere in the on-line Help?

Comment: I don't think so, no.

Comment: That's what I want. Thanks.

Comment: I found a bug. When using the command to run the script, though I gave absolute path of the script, it will use the default path in File->Open. For example, if my script path is 'C:\abc\123.s', and the default folder path is 'C:\def', then it will install the script of 'C:\def\123.s'. @BmyGuest

Comment: @ChenZX Not sure I fully understood your comment. However, any real bug is best reported to Gatan via the Bug&Issue reporting link at the bottom of https://www.gatan.com/resources/software . Just make sure to give enough detail to allow others to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your info. I will have more test before reporting this bug.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to have a look at the AddScriptFileToPackage function. This is covered in the DM on-line help at Scripting > Installing Scripts and Plugins.

A couple of questions on the dm-script tag address related issues, in detail. Please check out the following:

[How to convert DM script files into a plugin file gtk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53129923/how-to-convert-dm-script-files-s-into-a-plugin-file-gtk)

[How to import other source code files in DM script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60988664/how-to-import-other-source-code-files-in-dm-script)